# mySQL create a result set of two table alternating rows

Tags: mysql

I have a query that uses union to join two sub queries e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE postTypeId=1 (e.g. blog)
UNION
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE postTypeId=2 (e.g. news)
```

The result set that this approach generates positions the two sub-sets sequentially ("blog" then "news").

I want to create a a result set which interleaves the two, alternating between rows from the "blog" sub-set and the "news" sub-set.

I feel that there must be a simple way to do this, but I have failed to find it.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Nick

Comment: SQL's job is to give you the data. Displaying it in some special way is your application's job. Keep the queries simple, do the display logic in the application. This is trivially done with a single loop in whatever language your app is written in.

Comment: You know your query as it is above could be written as just `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE postTypeId=1 OR postTypeId=2` I assume you've done it as above to try and solve your problem that you're having, just letting you know incase.

Comment: @ThomasClayson, yes, the snippet is just to illustrate that getting the separate sub-sets is easy, but interleaving them...thats not.

Comment: @DanGrossman, I tend to try to keep the application logic simple rather than the SQL. I don't consider this a display logic issue. It's an issue of organising the data correctly before displaying it. Also, I don't see how this can be acheived "trivially with a single loop" when processing the data set. I think it requires the application to move backwards and forwards through the data to find relevant rows to output. Maybe I'm wrong. Thanks for the response anyway.

Comment: While I have some (well a lot) for the underlying assumption in Mr Grossman's comment, I wouldn't consider this particular case a wholly presentational issue, as it's ordering. For instance what if you wanted to paginate or limit.

Comment: Which I notice has some how sneaked into his own solution.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I'm not sure what to make of that comment. Yes, limiting was required in this case, but I didn't think it was relevant to the problem, so I didn't mention it. Perhaps I should have omitted it from the solution too, but I didn't think it would be a cause for confusion.

Comment: @NaNuk Mr Grossman's advice was interleaving should be treated as presentation layer and done client side. Other advice was that interleaving is adata function. At the time we took our stances there was no mention of a requirement for a limit, so when you snuck one in, you left the poor guy in an invidious position and those who disgareed blessed with 20/20 foresight :)

Comment: I don't think the presence of a limit either invalidates his position or supports mine. His assertion was that the ordering/interleaving of the data was a presentation issue. I disagreed. Whether the data needs limiting was not part of the question, though it did form a part of the solution. I have edited the solution to remove the limit and I think my position on Mr Grossmans assertion still stands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is solution that best works for me. It's not identical to any of the current proposals, so I have added it independently. @a, @b and @c are used to create row numbers per sub-set, meaning that in the combined results, 3 rows will share the same row number (a "row set"). This is used as the first order sort, and second order sort then orders the rows within the "row set".

```
SET @a = 0;
SET @b = 0;
SET @c = 0; 

SELECT * FROM(
  SELECT @a := @a + 1 AS sortOne, 1 AS sortTwo, posts.* FROM posts WHERE posts.postTypeId=3
    UNION
  SELECT @b := @b + 1 AS sortOne, 2 AS sortTwo, posts.* FROM posts WHERE posts.postTypeId=2
    UNION
  SELECT @c := @c + 1 AS sortOne, 3 AS sortTwo, posts.* FROM posts WHERE posts.postTypeId=1
) AS result ORDER BY sortOne, sortTwo
```

This solutions is derived/inspired by submitted solutions, but I don't think it appropriate to mark any of them as being an accepted solution in itself. So, credit where it's due to Thomas Clayson, Tony Hopkinson and rmunoz whose answers I've voted up. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Well, here is a novel way I can think of (not tested, but you'll get the gist):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS query, @n := @n + 1 AS rowNumber, posts.* FROM (select @n:=0), posts WHERE posts.postTypeId=1
    UNION
    SELECT 2 AS query, @n := @n + 1 AS rowNumber, posts.* FROM (select @n:=0), posts WHERE posts.postTypeId=2
) ORDER BY rowNumber, query;
```

So this will do the two queries and then order by first `rowNumber` and then by `query`. What you'll end up with is something like:

```
rowNumber | query
1         | 1
1         | 2
2         | 1
2         | 2
etc...
```

`SELECT @n=:0` resets the global variable `n` to 0 for the query and then the `@n := @n + 1` increments the value for each row.

If you need any more explanation let me know. I hope this works! :)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Set @current_row = 0
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT @current_row := @current_row + 1 as Position, posts.*
    FROM posts
    WHERE postTypeId=1
  UNION 
  SELECT @current_row, posts.*
    FROM posts
    WHERE postTypeId=2
) dummyTableName
ORDER BY position, postTypeId
```

maybe

Answer (score 2):

That's easy, you can add a parameter in your subquery, the parameter "rank", this way:

```
SET @rank=0;
SELECT @rank:=@rank+2 AS rank FROM posts WHERE postTypeId=1 (e.g. blog)
```

Then, you get:

```
0, ...
2, ...
```

If you do the same in the other query but init initializating rank to 1, you will get:

```
1, ...
3, ...
```

Finally "ORDER BY rank" and you will get posts and news mixed.