# Alternating Results of two SQL queries

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

This is probably not possible, but is there a way to output the results of two queries in alternating lines on a table?

For example if I have two tables that are trying to show one widget vs all of the widgets in its category, I would output each widget followed by the category averages, followed by widget 2 with its category averages in the next line. This would result in 4 lines. This is all assuming that widgets and their category averages are in two separate tables.

Sorry if this was confusing, I can clarify if I need to. I'm just trying to make it very simple for the final application to display in C#. It would probably be easier to do in the actual application but I'm not very familiar with C#...

Comment: What about querying the join of the two tables and using application code to place something on the first line and something else on the second?

Comment: You can do that using T-SQL (two cursors)

Comment: If you have a field to order by you can use one select with **union** and **order by**

Comment: @Federico - if the `order by` column is different in each query it's not that simple.

Comment: @Yosi - In that case you must use alias to each column.
And I suppose that the two results content similar data.. is all relative because we haven't the necessary information :P

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277665/mysql-create-a-result-set-of-two-table-alternating-rows

Answer (score 1):

First - as said in the comments - **If you have a field to order by you can use one select with union and order by.** and you are done.

**Even if not (different ordering on each query) it's stil possible** (assuming the two queries have the same exact schema):

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ColA) OrderA,1 OrderB,*
      FROM A
      UNION ALL
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ColB) + 1 OrderA,2 OrderB, *
      FROM B) C
ORDER BY OrderA, OrderB
```

**Disclaimer - I don't think it's a database operation.**

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using two table variables, two sort columns in each and a union all, but I would recommend that you join the two tables together and have one row for each widget (can have many columns one for category averages) and manage the display aspects of the design on the C# side

Answer (score 0):

If you have two temporary tables with identity columns, you can select a UNION of both tables with a careful manipulation of the row number:

```
declare @linesA table
(
    lineid int identity(1,1) primary key clustered,
    line varchar(80)
)

declare @linesB table
(
    lineid int identity(1,1) primary key clustered,
    line varchar(80)
)

insert into @linesA (line)
select 'A - 1' 
union select 'A - 2'
union select 'A - 3'

insert into @linesB (line)
select 'B - 1'
union select 'B - 2'
union select 'B - 3'

select
    lineid * 2 as RowNum,
    line from @linesA
union select
    lineid * 2 + 1 as RowNum,
    line from @linesB
order by RowNum
```

If you don't have an identity column, then create one with ROW_NUMBER() like this:

```
select
    row_number() over (order by line) * 2 as RowNum,
    line from @linesA
union select
    (row_number() over (order by line) * 2) + 1 as RowNum,
    line from @linesB
order by RowNum
```

Answer (score 0):

as updated in the comments.

first CTE is to generate only ODD and Even Numbers

remember that by default max allowed recursion is 100.

so we are setting value of @I to the number of records in to first table.

also notice the "OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);" which is required if number of records happen to be more that 100 and in that case recursion happen that many times.

```
        DECLARE @widget TABLE
        (
            widgetID        INT
            ,widgetName     sysname
            ,WidgetType     sysname
        )

        DECLARE @categoryAvg TABLE
        (
            WidgetType      sysname
            ,categoryAvg    sysname
        )

        INSERT INTO @widget( widgetID, widgetName,WidgetType )
        SELECT 1,'widget1','Wtype1'
        UNION ALL SELECT 2,'widget2','Wtype1'
        UNION ALL SELECT 2,'widget3','Wtype2'
        UNION ALL SELECT 2,'widget4','Wtype2'

        INSERT INTO @categoryAvg( WidgetType, categoryAvg )
        SELECT 'Wtype1',10 UNION ALL SELECT 'Wtype2',20


    declare @i int=100--MAX 100 ByDefault
    declare @StartOdd int=1 --To generate ODD numbers
    declare @StartEven int=2 --To generate EVEN numbers
    SELECT @i = COUNT(*) From @widget

    ;WITH CTE_OE(Rowid,OddNum,EvenNum)
    as
    (
        select 1,@StartOdd,@StartEven   
        union all   
        select t1.rowid+1,t1.OddNum+2,t1.EvenNum+2
        from CTE_OE t1
        where t1.rowid<@i
    ),
    CTE_1(WidgetType,OutputColumn,RowID)
    AS
    (
        SELECT t1.WidgetType,t1.OutputColumn,t2.OddNum
        FROM
        (
            SELECT  WidgetType
                    ,widgetName As OutputColumn
                    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY widgetName,WidgetType) RowID
            FROM @widget
        )t1
        JOIN CTE_OE t2
            ON t1.RowID=t2.Rowid
    ),
    CTE_2(OutputColumn,RowID)
    AS
    (
        Select  t1.OutputColumn
                ,t2.EvenNum
        From
        (
            SELECT  'Type'+ ' = ' + q1.WidgetType + ', Avg = ' + q1.categoryAvg As OutputColumn
                    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY q1.WidgetType) AS RowID
            FROM @categoryAvg q1
            JOIN CTE_1 q2
                on q1.WidgetType=q2.WidgetType
        )t1
        JOIN CTE_OE t2
            ON t1.RowID=t2.Rowid    

    )
    Select OutputColumn
    From
    (
        Select OutputColumn,RowID from CTE_1
        union all
        select OutputColumn,RowID from CTE_2
    )qry
    order by RowID
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

[image]

Comment: Judging by the output, this is more or less what I'm going for. I am linking these tables on w.widgettype = c.widgettype. Will this solution match my widget with it's average based on the type?

Comment: if linking between Table is widgettype then in the output you should have widgettype not widgetName. because one or many widget may have same widgettype. is that ok if each widget of same type has same categoryAvg displayed below it? if it is not ok and if you still need widgetName in output you need to give more info like how many widget are per type. if that info stored somewhere you can apply "weighted average" or some other calculation you want.

Comment: I have updated the code with assumption that you want to see same Average Value for Each Widget falling in same Type.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know C# personally, so I don't know how hard/easy this would be to do within the application, but just as a side thought, one way you might be able to approach it within the SQL query without having to make the two separate queries and alternate display and all... an option might be to just do a join and display results side by side.  What I mean is you could do something along the lines of:

```
SELECT Widget.Name, Widget.Category, Widget.Speed, Category.Speed AS AvgSpeed
FROM Widget
INNER JOIN Category
ON Widget.Category=Category.Name;
```

Then you would end up having a table something along the lines of

```
Name Category Speed AvgSpeed
W1   Sample   1ms   2ms
```